# How would you debug this error in python, when there is an error in input?

Tags: python, input

I am beginning with programming, starting in Python.
I was trying to ask the user (using input) to enter his name and then print it with some other words. But as you can see in the screenshot an error has occurred, I don't know how to fix it, so if there is anyone else that knows the trick, please let me know.
Also I was kinda shocked when I saw my Python version although I have downloaded and installed Python 3.9 to my computer is there a way how could I upgrade the version? I was looking on the internet but haven't found any.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wasm.png)

Here is the code in written form:
name = input("Your name: ")
print(name)

Comment: The problem is your Python version, so just worry about fixing that. Your code is broken in 2, but fine in 3. If you click the version in the bottom left, there may be an option to change the interpreter used. If not there, it may be in the settings.

Comment: I can see 3 options: Enter interpreter path, Python 2.7.16 64-bit and Use default Python interpreter path

Comment: I would try "enter interpreter path", then give it the path to the Python 3.9 installation.